# How to change HashMap<String, Long> to LinkedHashMap<String, Long> via Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm new in Java and now I try lambda/stream.

How can I sort the `Map` by value?

I tried as follows, but it's not correct:

```
time = time.entrySet().stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
           .collect(Collectors.toMap((String)Map.Entry::getKey, 
                      (Long)Map.Entry::getValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

I found the following method, but don't know how to use it:

```
Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,   
                        Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,   
                        BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,   
                        Supplier<M> mapSupplier)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify the merge function.

```
time = time.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                                    (v1,v2)->v1,
                                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

BTW, assuming that `time` is not a raw `Map`, you don't have to cast the key to `String` and the value to `Long`. And trying to cast the method references `Map.Entry::getKey` and `Map.Entry::getValue` is wrong anyway, since the method references implement the `Function` interface, so they shouldn't be cast to `String` or `Long` if you want your code to pass compilation.

Comment: Great thanks! I see it work. By can you help to understand- what (v1,v2)-> v1 means? It means that if v1 and v2 has the same value, first one in map will be v1, right?

Comment: @Khilarian it means that if the Stream maps two values to the same key, it will use that merge function, which will take the 2 values and return the first value. Since your Stream source is a Map, there will be no values to merge, so you can pass any merge function here and it won't affect the result.

Comment: thanks ) it's easier to understand that I read earlier))